# Can I use the OpenSearch of "Stack Overflow for Teams" with Firefox?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, opensearch

If I look at the HTML of a "Stack Overflow for Teams" I'm using, I can see this line:

```html
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="<Stack@Company>" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

This is the OpenSearch description format. You can read more about that on MDN Web Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch

If a page includes such a description file, browsers such as Firefox can integrate their search into the tool bar.

However, this does *not* work with the Stack Overflow for Teams instance I'm using as the description file is invalid, according to Firefox.

Therefore my question:
*Does Stack Overflow for Teams support OpenSearch in Firefox?*
If it is supported, is this a bug?

Below are two screenshots to illustrate this:

[image: Adding Stackenterprise to Firefox]

[image: Error message]

I'm using Firefox 89 on macOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: the OpenSearch.xml found in a Teams instance doesn't comply to the 1.1 standard of OpenSearch.

```xml
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>[team]</ShortName>
    <Description>Search [team]: Q&A for </Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/channels/Img/favicon.ico?v=42</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://channels.ds.stackexchange.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

The Url element doesn't allow for a method attribute but if we overcome that issue (the schema doesn't seem to be checked) the `template` attribute refers to a domainname that doesn't exist: `channels.ds.stackexchange.com`. Compare that to the Stack Overflow template value: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}`.

Conclusion: You can't use OpenSearch for your Stack Overflow for Teams right now. I don't see a reason why it couldn't work. The value of the template attribute needs to be changed to `https://stackoverflow.com/c/[team]/search?q={searchTerms}&searchOn=1` and we should be good to go.

That bug needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm unsure whether I should mark your answer as accepted (after all, it explains all my questions in detail) or should wait for the Stackoverflow team to answer. Is there a way to reach out to the team to get this bug fixed?

Comment: This site is precisely the place; developers will see your question (bug report) here. It is your choice whether to accept rene's answer or not. The truth is, it doesn't really matter. There's no rep on Meta, so he doesn't really benefit in any tangible way from having his answer accepted. On the other hand, if you do accept it, it's not like staff is going to ignore the bug. @AndreM96

Comment: Thanks. Then it answers my question. I very much appreciate your clarification.